# Shopify API how to generate invoice , shipping label and shipping manifest?

Tags: node.js, api, meteor, shopify

Hi i am trying to get shipping label , invoice and shipping manifest for an order on shopify using API

I am able to get orders using :

```html
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://<api key>:<password>@hostname/admin/orders.json',
  qs: { fulfillment_status: 'partial' },
  headers: 
   { 'postman-token': '2564af8e-df07-3bb8-3282-4956b70025b7',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

But I could not find any API endpoints for Shipping Label , Invoice , shipping manifest

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create an invoice using the Shopify API.

However, you can use an [invoicing app like Sufio](https://sufio.com/shopify/invoice/?src=https://stackoverflow.com/) to obtain PDF invoices for orders in your store.

This page explains [how to generate links to invoices in a Shopify store](https://sufio.com/articles/shopify/include-links-invoices/customer-account-page/).

For example, if your store's address is `shop.url`, use the following link to download a PDF invoice for order with ID `order.id` and number `order.number`.

```
{{ shop.url }}/apps/sufio/invoice/download/?id={{ order.id }}&number={{ order.order_number }}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you think Sufio gathers the information to create invoices if not via the Shopify API?